# How can I convert an OpenOffice Writer document (.odt) to multiple HTML files with navigation?

Tags: html, export, openoffice-writer

I have an OpenOffice Writer document (.odt) with a table of contents, sections, subsections, etc.
Is there a quick way to convert (export) this into multiple HTML files with a navigation sidebar, converting the sections into links?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Unzip the odt, parse the XML and make the HTML file yourself.
- Use OpenOffice to export the document to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to export HTML from OpenOffice or LibreOffice:

- Use File > Export, then select file type XHMTL. However, this creates one big HTML file, not multiple files.
- Use File > Save as, then select file type HTML document. This creates one big HTML file which is similar but not fully equal to the one above.
- Use File > Send > Create HTML document. In the following dialog, you can select a style used in the document based on which the document is split into multiple HTML files. However, I did not get this to work properly. My document is always split on level 1, no matter what I selected here.
- Use File > Wizards > Web page. You will get multiple settings to chose from. However, this does not work at all for me. It either fails completely or it does not produce the expected output.

The last two solutions were found on the OpenOffice Wiki at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Getting_Started/Saving_Writer_documents_as_web_pages

As a conclusion, I cannot provide a complete solution. I am still looking for a good way to solve this problem.